# Free ISO Burner application uses up all the space on the disk when trying to burn the Ubuntu iso on a DVD

Tags: burning, livedvd

With Windows XP ending support next Tuesday, I was scrapped for time to find another replacement OS. I was told to install a Linux-based operating system as a replacement and I decided to try this version out. I didn't want to pay someone to install it for me, so I tried it on my own.

I downloaded "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS- 32-bit" (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and waited about an hour for it to download the 730MB file. It was an image file (ISO file), so I used  "Free ISO Burner" to attempt to burn it. After three failed attempts to burn the file on a 4.7GB disk, I extracted the file with Winrar. I left the room and came back to find that the Ubuntu menu was up. The 730MB OS took up ALL of the disk space for the 4.7 GB DVD for some reason. Anyways, I clicked "Demo and Full Installation," then clicked on "Help Me Boot From a Live CD," since the computer didn't boot from the DVD after four attempts. It looked like it was working, but it stopped about the quarter of the way with the message:

```
An error has occurred: Permission denied. For more information please see the log file: c:\docume~1\hp\locals~1\temp\wubi-12.04.4-rev280.log
```

Link to Log (http://paste.ubuntu.com/7205612/)

And that's my problem so far. Do I erase everything that was written on that disk and try to burn it over? Do I need an additional program to run it?

My specs:

- HP (L2000)
- Windows XP Professional Edition (32-bit)
- Processor: AMD Turion(tm) 64 Mobile Technology ML-40
- Hard drive: 93GB worth of space available (45GB used)
- RAM: 1024MB
- Display adapter: ATI Mobility Radeon Xpress 200 (Video RAM: 128MB)

Comment: Did you see the instructions on [ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) ?

Comment: @Mateo Added it now. Done.

Comment: Please add the log file too!

Comment: @Braiam I can't, the log is too long and used up all of the characters.

Comment: Upload it in http://paste.ubuntu.com, [edit] your question and add the linke

Comment: @Braiam I've pasted the link now.

Comment: You don't "extract" iso images, this is kind of a misfeature that winrar provides.

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu iso should not take up all the space on the DVD. It is possible that the program you used to burn the iso, Free ISO Burner, got to the last stage of the disk burning where it says something like *Finalizing...* and then tried to eject the disk automatically and failed, possibly due to some hardware issue with the optical drive. So Free ISO Burner started burning all over again and that's why it filled up the disk.

To solve this you have to watch the application when the disk is being burned, and when you get to the end close the application with the mouse and eject the DVD manually. I also recommend that instead of Free ISO Burner you use Windows Disc Image Burner for Windows 7/8/10 or Infra Recorder as ubuntu.com recommends at [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows). The disk burning speed for most disk burning applications is set to Maximum by default. For burning an iso you should always set the disk burning speed to Minimum. Also you should watch the disk burning process carefully, and when you get to the end after the finalizing, you should close the application manually before it starts all over again.

If this seems nerve-wracking to you, there is another way to do it - you can write the Ubuntu to a USB flash drive of 2GB size or larger using an application called Rufus.  For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the USB flash drive should be 4GB or larger. For step-by-step instructions for how to create a bootable Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674441/what-is-the-proper-way-of-creating-installation-media-from-ubuntu-iso/674454#674454).

Comment: A better recommendation would be using a USB...

Comment: @Alvar I added it to my answer as well as a link to step-by-step instructions for making an Ubuntu live USB for installing Ubuntu.