# Why is it a "hardware error" when trying to burn to DVD-RW?

Tags: system-installation, iso, dvd

I'm using Free ISO burner to write one of the newer Ubuntu ISOs to a disc, but for some reason Free ISO gives me a "hardware error" immediately when trying to write it to a DVD-RW. I've put in a DVD-R and it's just fine. Why is this?

As a side note: These DVD-RWs have been wonderful for writing movies to them, why not an operating system? Also, it was blank when i put it in, so I'm asking here cuz it has something to do with DVD-RWs and operating systems.

Comment: Free ISO burner seems to be an Windows software. Try another software instead. Windows 10 has an inbuilt ISO burner.

Comment: Please check, whether the Drive can read yellow or green colored discs. If not, then the lens of the drive might require a cleaning. I got a power calibration error on my drive and cleaning fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free ISO Burner application uses up all the space on the disk when trying to burn the Ubuntu iso on a DVD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443487/free-iso-burner-application-uses-up-all-the-space-on-the-disk-when-trying-to-bur)